# How do I set an optional xcodatamodel attribute?

Tags: xcode, core-data

I heard there was a checkbox or something but I can't find it anywhere in the XCode interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be right there in the data model inspector panel.
Press <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd> to show that panel.
Or select the right one in the *view* button group and select the right tab.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to XCode and don't know the hotkeys for all the panels, or even which ones exist.

Comment: you can show those panels with the rightmost of the three buttons above the label _view_ too. Check them out, there is a lot of useful stuff in those panels.